# Maven: Combining multiple module jars into one war file?

Tags: java, maven

I have a project `babybird` which has 3 components `persistence`, `business` and `service`

in `babybird`'s `pom.xml` I have following

```
   <modules>
        <module>persistence</module>
        <module>business</module>
        <module>service</module>
    </modules>
```

when I run `mvn clean install`, I see

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] babybird  ......................................... SUCCESS [2.801s]
[INFO] persistence ....................................... SUCCESS [3.321s]
[INFO] business .......................................... SUCCESS [0.832s]
[INFO] service ........................................... SUCCESS [0.694s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.168s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jan 22 12:09:48 PST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/50M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and each one of these modules generate a jar file.

**Question**: How can I combine them into one `babybird.war`?
I am new to Maven and do not know what to look for to accomplish this task, please provide the pointers

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's fairly simple. Create another module named `web` or similar:

```
<modules>
    <module>persistence</module>
    <module>business</module>
    <module>service</module>
    <module>web</module>
</modules>
```

`web` module should depend on all others:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>...</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

and have `war` packaging:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

You'll also need `web.xml` in `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`. That's it.

Comment: @ThilinaSampath https://medium.com/@eranda/combine-multiple-springboot-applications-into-a-single-application-649514e7a447