# Spring boot + angular 2 Heroku deployment

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, heroku

I have a big issue. I'm trying to deploy Spring Boot + Angular 2 web app on heroku but don't know how to do it. I tried several things including:

- Making a .war file and deploying it to heroku (source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43602712/angular-2-and-spring-boot-deploy-to-war))
- Deploying project as standard java application (source [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#introduction))

but none of these worked. The first attempt didn't work because I constatly got 404 not found, and the second one didn't work due to, I think, some jar file wasn't found in the location which was described in the Procfile.
Can anyone give me a link, an example, or write a step by step instruction how to achieve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most simple way to do it:

1. run `ng build` in angular 2 project root (if you are using angular-cli) and copy the content of dist folder to src/main/resources/static/.
2. create Procfile (for maven):

   web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/*.jar
3. commit and push changes.

   Also, you need spring-boot-starter-web present in dependencies. Which has embedded tomcat and automatically configured to serve static content from the static folder.

Comment: The problem here is that my dist folder doesn't get generated.

Comment: @kantagara, If you generated an angular project with [angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/) 
 everything should work. Run: ng new project_new --ng4

Comment: @kantagara also you may find [this](https://youtu.be/k8r76d8QzXs?t=39m41s) useful.

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. I couldn't find the exact cause why my dist folder didn't get generated, so I created brand new angular project, installed all the required dependencies and transfered all of my source files to that project. After that i run ng build and it generated the dist folder. The next problem I had was not getting any 404 not found error from spring, but I handled that with the solution described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38516667/springboot-angular2-how-to-handle-html5-urls .

Answer (score 3):

If you deploy your app as a standard Java application, you can combine it with the Node.js buildpack to run `ng build` during the Heroku build.

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/java
$ git push heroku master
```

The Node.js buildpack will detect your `package.json`, install Node.js and run `npm`. Then the Java build can proceed as normal.

There is a guide for doing something very similar but with Grunt: [Using Grunt with Java and Maven to Automate JavaScript Tasks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-grunt-with-java-and-maven-to-automate-javascript-tasks)

Answer (score 1):

Use JHipster: https://jhipster.github.io

Once installed, run:

```
$ yo jhipster
```

Then run

```
$ yo jhipster:heroku
```

Comment: Thanks. But honestly this looks like way too much work for an exisiting project to get deployed. Or am I wrong?